# Find records where field ends with other field

Tags: mongodb

I have `title`, `director` and `englishTitle` fields.

```
{
  title: "Iron Man",
  director: "Someone Important",
  englishTitle: "Iron Man Someone Important"
}
```

I need to find all the records that have `englishTitle` ending with `director`'s value.

How can I perform such query with MongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described here, you can use regex : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

In your case it would be

```
{ englishTitle: { $regex: /^.*director$/ } }
```

---

For finding the value of director, I suppose you can use "$where"

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/

```
db.myCollection.find( function() { 
  var possibleDirector = this.englishTitle.substr(this.englishTitle.length - 1 - this.director.length);
  return (possibleDirector === this.director);
} );
```

(maybe it would require little polishing like checking the length to not obtaint negative value in substr)

Comment: Thanks but I need to match the value of `director`, not the literal `director` string